# I have mongo db in a docker container and I want to connect my app which is running on another container

Tags: docker, flask-mongoengine

I used flask_mongoengine to connect to the db
as follows:

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
'host': 'mongodb://mongo:27017/db_name'
    }
```

mongo is the name of the container, but i am getting the following error:

> "pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 605cb104a9a518d390b9ba99, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongo', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongo:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)>]>"

Comment: share your commands to run docker containers. to resolve your problem I should simulate you environment.

Comment: How do you run containers? `docker-compose`? `Dockerfile`? Both? Share us them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two container are not on the same network.

Possible solutions:

- use `docker-compose` so that, by default, they are running within the same network
- use `docker run --network host mongo` to use [host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/). Note: doesn't work with Docker Desktop for Win or Mac
- manually attach the same network to both the container. After having launched mongo and the flask application, `docker network connect network-name flask-container-name`. You can retrieve the network name by inspecting the mongo container or `docker network list`